spresenseでのStep Counterの使用について
spresenseの開発初心者です。
Arduino IDEの開発環境で歩数のセンシングを行いたく、公式チュートリアルの
「4. Sensing チュートリアル」
「4.1. Step Counter を使ってみよう」
に取り組もうと考えています。
しかし、紹介されているセンサーボードがいずれも販売終了しており、取り組めない現状です。
また、以前に同様の質問が投稿されていたようですが、回答されていたセンサーボードは現在販売されていませんでした。
そこで、spresenseで加速度センサーを用いてStep Counterを使用するためには、(1)何のセンサーボードを購入して(2)サンプルコードをどう変更すれば良いのか教えていただきたいです。

チュートリアルで紹介されている製品は以下2つのセンサーを搭載していますが、ステップカウンターに必要なのは "BMI160" なので、このセンサー名で探して同じものを使用してみてください。


BMI160（3軸加速度・3軸ジャイロ）
BMP280（気圧・温度センサ）


センサーが同じであればライブラリも基本的にはそのまま使用できるものと思われますが、配線については実際の製品仕様に合わせて読み替える必要があります。
以下は "BMI160" 搭載のセンサーモジュールを検索した一例ですが、動作を保証するものではありません。
https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B0BZPG9GBG/
https://electronicwork.shop/items/664cb769b37ea4120ba68639
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005006719170129.html

ご回答ありがとうございます。とりあえずそれを使って試してみようと思います。

蛇足っぽいですが、こちらのボードは、すでに販売終了のようなので、なかなか入手できないですよね。
https://www.switch-science.com/products/5258
こちらにBMI270を使ったボードがある用です。
https://www.switch-science.com/products/9870
物理センサーを変更するやり方は、こちらに書いてあります。
4.1.2. Step Counter の物理センサを変更してみる
https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_step_counter_%E3%81%AE%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B5%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8B
こちらを参考に、BMI270に変更してみるとできると思います。
Arduinoのライブラリは、こちらにも
https://github.com/fooping-tech/Spresense_6dof_add_on
こちらにもあります。
https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_BMI270_Arduino_Library
